# Why do I have "500 Server Error" on my Java appengine app after 5 years without having any problem?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I started this website (http://speaklikewater.appspot.com/) using Java appengine 5 years ago. It uses some datastore files.

**I had never had any problem since then.**

But yesterday, I see this error  "**500 Server Error**" when I visit my website.

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
> complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

I looked into the log file

[image]

It seems that I have "**Billing disabled. Shutting down instance.**" but I have never been worrying about Billing stuff since I launched the site.

I used the free version, they control the number of queries. But the site only has a few queries a day.

But this error will be reset after 24 hours. It has been over 24 hours already but I still have this problem.

**Could you tell me how to fix it?**

**Note:** They sent me this email

> Add your payment information by January 31, 2021, to continue using
> your App Engine standard applications. Hi Hung,
>
> On November 30, 2019, the App Engine standard environment began using
> Cloud Build during deployments. Cloud Build, along with all Google
> Cloud products, requires a valid form of payment. At that time, we
> asked you to link your App Engine projects to a billing account with a
> valid form of payment to continue deploying to your projects.
>
> Starting January 31, 2021, all App Engine projects must be linked to a
> billing account with a valid form of payment to continue running. App
> Engine apps that are not linked to a billing account with a valid form
> of payment by January 31, 2021, will be shut down. Running instances
> will be terminated and no new instances will be able to start until a
> payment method is added to the project.
>
> This change does not impact existing App Engine Free Tiers. If your
> usage remains within the free tier quota, you will not incur App
> Engine charges. However, any usage above the free tier quotas will
> result in charges. Before this change, if you exceeded the free tier
> usage, your app stopped running until the daily quota reset.
>
> What do I need to know? Requiring a payment method helps prevent fraud
> and abuse, and aligns App Engine with the rest of Google Cloud. This
> allows us to spend more time delivering new features and providing
> support to you as your business grows on App Engine.
>
> Projects using App Engine Flex or the following App Engine Standard
> runtimes have always required a valid form of payment and are not
> impacted by this change:
>
> Python 3 Java 11 PHP 7 Go 1.11/1.12+ Ruby NodeJS What do I need to do?
> To avoid disruption, follow the instructions to create a new Cloud
> Billing account (if you don’t have one) and enable billing on your App
> Engine projects.
>
> If you rely on Free Tier as a cost control mechanism, we recommend you
> consider the following alternatives to manage your App Engine costs:
>
> Set the max_instances setting to 1 in app.yaml, to reduce the risk of
> exceeding the Free Tier. This setting limits your app’s scaling
> ability, but isn’t a hard limit, and may allow excess usage that may
> increase your bill. Set a Cloud budget alert to notify you when you
> are close to exceeding your budget. Manually disable your app.
> However, this only prevents charges related to actively running your
> app, such as instance hours, networking, etc. You will continue to be
> billed for fixed costs like Cloud Storage capacity while your app is
> disabled. Programmatically disable your app to limit further costs
> once a certain budget threshold is met.

Comment: Vendors can change their policies whenever they want subject to TOS. If you want to use Google Cloud, set up billing and payments. Note - Google can delete your resources for non-payment, so take this notice seriously and follow their instructions.

Comment: This is serious problem. I have same problem on GAE projects that does **not have billing account**. I'm also looking for clarified document about this.

Comment: @Tom, Does John Hanley's comment answers your question ?

Comment: I have the same issue here. I noticed today this same behaviour. I believe that, unfortunately, some free usage policy has changed.

Answer (score 3):

Per that email, and the [Google Cloud's App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/payment-instrument), you need to add a payment method, even if you are only using the free tier.

"While you must provide a payment method for your accounts, the App Engine free tier has not changed and is not going away."

Answer (score 2):

The rules changed starting on August 9, 2021:

> As of August 9, 2021, all App Engine apps require a payment method to
> continue running. This requirement applies to apps in all App Engine
> runtimes, including Java 8, Python 2.7, PHP 5, and Go 1.11 apps in the
> standard environment.

Before it, a payment method was only required to deploy applications.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/payment-instrument